# How do I test the data to fit to the Poisson distribution with goodfit?

Tags: r, poisson, p-value, goodness-of-fit

I have a data set with car arrivals per minute.

I drew a histogram and fit to the Poisson distribution with the following R codes.

```
#Aladdin Arrivals
Datast <- read.csv("Vehiclecount.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=",")
hist(Datast$Arrival, xlab="Arrivals", 
  probability = TRUE,col=16, ylim = c(0,0.2), xlim =c(0, 30),    
  main = "Arrivals from Aladdin Street")
lines(dpois(x=0:25, lambda=13.20), col=2,lwd=3)
legend("topright", c("Probability of Vehicle Arrivals ", 
    "Poisson Distribution Curve"),  fill=c(col=16, col=2))
```

The code above successfully ran and I got the fitted lines over the histogram.

But when I want to use the `goodfit()` function to know how the p-value is I got following error;

> "Error in optimize(chi2, range(count)) : 'xmin' not less than 'xmax'”

```
dfs <- dpois(x=1:25, lambda=13.20)
summary(dfs)
goodfit(dfs, type="poisson", method="MinChisq")
```

How I can solve this issue ? Is there another function to use?

Comment: Please, could you share a sample of your data, in order to help you?

Comment: T.Period x Arrival Rate
7 1 4,87
8 2 12,54
9 3 10,89
10 4 11,46
11 5 12,18
12 6 12,85
13 7 13,72
14 8 17,49
15 9 18,34
16 10 20,83
17 11 13,09
18 12 13,23
19 13 10,07

Comment: I added the sample data as an image in answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying `goodfit` (you should say it's from the `vcd` package, BTW) to the wrong thing.  The first argument should be your count data: try

```
vcd::goodfit(Datast$Arrival, type="poisson")
```

Comment: Yes it works in this way, thanks..
How should I follow when I want to measure the compatibility of this data set with the Chisquare test and get the p value?